# Floating elements inside a fixed positioned container

Tags: html, css

Usually when you float an element and the container has no height then the container has no height. But if the container has a fixed position it stretched around the floated div. Why is this?

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}

.box_1 {
  height: 4rem;
  background-color: red;
  width: 10%;
  float: right;
}

.box_2 {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box_1">

  </div>

  <div class="box_2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because the container is defined around the div.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting "Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents." Fixed positioned elements count as absolutely positioned elements for this purpose.